# Reactjs: Simple jQuery click events not firing anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, css-transitions

Tools: React v 0.14   Jquery 1.11.2

**I've hit a wall and I'm not sure if it's because I'm not sure if it's because of a big Reactjs jQuery no-no that I could be unaware of.**

Now I know that React can handle click events for me,
  **but I just wanted to test out some css-transitions on my page and I've already built event handlers in jQuery** that work on a standard html version of basically the same application(non-Reactjs).

**Now that I'm trying it on my reactjs version though onClick events from my jQuery file are not firing.**

To give you a quick idea of the probelm here's a snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);
    console.log("This is will output! yah!!");
    $('.burger').on('click', function() {
      console.log("Oh crap,not outputting when I click! boo!!");
...
```

**Is there any major reactjs reason(virtual-dom, jQuery compatibility issues) no-no I'm not aware of that could be causing this failure?** Or is it kosher to do what I'm(at least for fast testing reasons) and it should work so long as I coded up the jQuery right?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '.burger', function() {`

Comment: @Tushar you rock! Could you add that as an answer so I can give you credit? Thx!

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help